# Generating Fedex Shipping Labels

Tags: soap, wsdl, fedex

I'm using Fedex web services and would like to regenerate a shipping label. Is there a SOAP request where I can supply a tracking number and have fedex return a pdf label, or do I need to save the generated pdf when using the ShipService to create the shipment? Generating the pdf on the fly would be cleaner than having to store each generated pdf.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66559164/how-to-generate-a-return-label-for-the-customer-from-fedex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no FedEx API to regenerate/reprint the label.

You have to store it on your side or somewhere in the cloud.

Comment: @likeitlikeit I can't provide official support link because FedEx API & Documentation is only available to registered developers and cannot be redistributed officially. The only correct way is to register yourself and get all necessary docs. If you look at their API guide you will find that there is no such API. So if you like to check register at http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/resources.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Shiprush SDK, the label can be refetched from the Shiprush system. When you go direct to fedex api, then you have to handle saving the label yourself, and managing the reprint process yourself.